# HTMLUnit not return completely loaded page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit, sourceforge

I'm trying to get the content of the web [page](https://r.onliner.by/pk/#bounds%5Blb%5D%5Blat%5D=53.83186504485333&bounds%5Blb%5D%5Blong%5D=27.39028930664063&bounds%5Brt%5D%5Blat%5D=53.96497315018515&bounds%5Brt%5D%5Blong%5D=27.73361206054688), namely the right side of the page with the list of apartments (div elements with class="classified"). When viewing the page in browser it's clear that it uses JavaScript.

I'm using HtmlUnit for Java and especially *waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000)* method for waiting till the JavaScript is finished. However, it still doesn't work for me and I get the same HTML w/o elements showing apartment pages as by initial call.

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.client").setLevel(Level.OFF);

URL url = new URL("https://r.onliner.by/pk/#bounds%5Blb%5D%5Blat%5D=53.75074091071493&bounds%5Blb%5D%5Blong%5D=27.301025390625004&bounds%5Brt%5D%5Blat%5D=54.04527964804286&bounds%5Brt%5D%5Blong%5D=27.822875976562504");

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000); 

System.out.println(page.asXml());

webClient.close();
```

Enabling *setThrowExceptionOnScriptError* shows some exceptions in JavaScript code (I'm not sure if it is relevant to the question as there are no such issues in browser).

I've also tried some other methods like

```
// option 2
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(50000);

// option 3
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(50000);

// option 4
JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
while (manager.getJobCount() > 0)
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

but nothing worked. Could you please advise how to get content of the page?

Comment: What are the Exceptions? I also added `webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController(){
            @Override
            public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });` to help processing ajax calls. Otherwise oyu can also try to change the BrowserVersion. These Browsers handle javascript differently.

Comment: @Niklas, thanks for reply. I've added `setAjaxController`, but it didn't help - the result is still not complete page. Changing between browsers didn't help as well (tried CHROME, FIREFOX_60, BEST_SUPPORTED options).

Comment: @Niklas Exceptions trace is too huge for posting here, but all of the errors during Javascript execution refer to`Exception invoking send Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u (https://yastatic.net/pcode/adfox/loader.js#1) in
function () {4 === n.readyState && (n.status === d || n.status === l ? t.onLoad(n.response) : t.onError(n.statusText, n.status));}`
Please, let me know if I should send you the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Problems HTMLUnit has with JavaScript, you need to find a workaround. Seeing that you know which element you want, you can implement a while loop. This could look somehow like this:

```
while(!page.asText().contains(„<div id=\„exmaple-id\">“)){
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(500);
    }
```

If you are afraid of being catched in this loop, you could add a counting variable to the while condition. As far as my exeprience goes, is this a reliable way of dealing with this kind of delay.

Comment: yes, thank you. However, while loop is not a solution for this case - it is endless for the provided web page.
It seems that the HtmlUnit browser does not see the result of Javascript code (no matter how long to wait). And the question is why.

Comment: What exactly do you even want to do with that? The site seems very depended on javascript, after some searching i found the API-Interface which basically sends you all the information in a very clean json: https://pk.api.onliner.by/search/apartments?bounds%5Blb%5D%5Blat%5D=53.75074091071493&bounds%5Blb%5D%5Blong%5D=27.301025390625004&bounds%5Brt%5D%5Blat%5D=54.04527964804286&bounds%5Brt%5D%5Blong%5D=27.822875976562504 (The root of the url is https://pk.api.onliner.by/search/apartments? + your params from the given url

Comment: You're right, I didn't know about that. Thanks a lot for providing the link and for support!